# Why is <app-root> rendering another <app-root> within it, which contains my routed component?

Tags: angular, typescript, router-outlet

I have a lazy-loaded, multi-module Angular 7.2.2 application that seems to be creating a copy of the main `AppComponent`'s template within itself, then rendering the routed component within that.

Here is my attempt at a complete but concise preamble (I can't reproduce this in a plunkr). Please do ask for any details I have missed.

## The Preamble

I have an `index.html` file that contains ordinary HTML, and an `<app-root>` element within its `<body>`. This is the only place in the project that `app-root` tag appears. This file is referenced in `angular.json`'s `projects.app.architect.build.options.index` property.

The main `AppComponent` is declared as

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <message-banner [show]="showMessage" [message]="message"></message-banner>
  `,
  providers: [AuthenticationService, AuthenticationGuard, MessagingService]
})
```

The rest of the logic in `AppComponent` simply mediates the `show` and `message` content for app-wide notifications. I have no router-outlet hooking and no direct DOM manipulation.

My `main.ts` bootstraps the application as usual

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

import { hmrBootstrap } from './hmr';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

const bootstrap = () => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

if (environment.hmr && module['hot']) {
  hmrBootstrap(module, bootstrap);
}
else {
  bootstrap().catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

From the following `AppModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    appRoutes,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    SharedGenericModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MessageBannerComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
    appRoutingProviders,
    ChoosePasswordGuard,
    LoadingBarService,
    Title,
    UserService
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Using these `app.routes` (small excerpt)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'shop',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'shop',
        data: { key: 'shop' },
        loadChildren: "./modules/shop.module#ShopModule",
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'car/:id',
        data: { key: 'car' },
        loadChildren: "./modules/car.module#CarModule",
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        // This one has child routes, which I will add if needed
        path: 'workOrder',
        data: { key: 'workOrder' },
        loadChildren: "./modules/workOrder.module#WorkOrderModule",
      }
      // And many more
    ]
  }
]

export const appRoutes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  enableTracing: false,
  onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
});
```

## The Problem

Once the application has stabilized, the resulting DOM looks like this:

```
<body>
  <app-root ng-version="7.2.2">

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <app-root>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <default-routed-component _nghost-c0>...</default-routed-component>
      <message-banner ng-reflect-show="true" ng-reflect-message="[object Object]">...</message-banner>
    </app-root>

    <message-banner ng-reflect-show="true" ng-reflect-message="[object Object]">...</message-banner>

  </app-root>
</body>
```

Note that the inner `<app-root>` is not decorated with an `ng-version`.

Also, I can only programmatically communicate with the inner `<message-banner>`, the outer one seems disconnected. But messages generated before the first route is loaded (before the application stabilizes) are sent to *both* instances of the message banner.

## Questions

Why is my app instantiating two `<app-root>`s with two `<router-outlets>`, but only using one of them. How can I prevent it from doing so?

I need to retain one app-wide `<message-banner>`, but I obviously want **exactly one**. Were it not for the duplication of that component, it might simply be an mysterious inconvenience - the app works perfectly well in all respects otherwise.

Comment: Update: I don't completely follow the meaning of _"Create a real, different home component. Don't reuse the root component for your home page."_ I created a new, modern app with `ng new` and that's _precisely_ what the example app does: the main app component selects the index.html's `<app-root>`, and _is_ the home page, with a template that doesn't even include a `<router-outlet>`.

Comment: Could you create an [mcve] using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)?

Comment: @Igor I'll do my best; our application is enormous. Please stand by (I'll delete this comment and update when it's done).

Comment: Can I see the appRoutes you have declared inside the imports of AppModule?

Comment: @emkay Absolutely! Added a sample of the patterns we have, and the way they're included. `workOrder` has child routes (i.e., `workOrder/part/:id`, `workOrder/shop/:id`) which are handled entirely in another module. I omitted them for brevity.

Comment: @Igor Got it, if you're curious. Sorry I wasn't able to reproduce the problem in Stackblitz (that's usually a crucial debugging step for me, but I spend hours just making the mcve, and had to abandon it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is extremely obvious in retrospect.

The main *AppComponent* - which contained the application's only `<router-outlet>` and common code I wanted to use throughout the application - was bootstrapped from the main AppModule **and instantiated a second time** by the Router as the default route's component, which then loaded feature modules as child routes.

The fix was simply to remove the AppComponent and child routing; so to change `app.routes.ts` from

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'shop',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'shop',
        data: { key: 'shop' },
        loadChildren: "./modules/shop.module#ShopModule",
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
  ...
  }
]
```

to

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'shop',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'shop',
    data: { key: 'shop' },
    loadChildren: "./modules/shop.module#ShopModule",
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this, I don't understand why, but you should create another main component with another `<router-outlet>` tag (apart from app.component.ts - this is the principal component) and call it from the parent routs. for example

Step one:
ng generate c layout/inicio

```
App
 - Layout
     -inicio.component.ts
     -inicio.component.html
```

And here is the magic =>

code: inicio.component.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: InicioComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'shop',
        data: { key: 'shop' },
        loadChildren: "./modules/shop.module#ShopModule",
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'car/:id',
        data: { key: 'car' },
        loadChildren: "./modules/car.module#CarModule",
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        // This one has child routes, which I will add if needed
        path: 'workOrder',
        data: { key: 'workOrder' },
        loadChildren: "./modules/workOrder.module#WorkOrderModule",
      }
      // And many more
    ]
  }
]
```

If your lazy loads module is configurate correctly, should works it.
I hope this can help you, greetings from Chile.